# Multiple conditions with 'if' statement

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How to Set multiple conditions with 'if' statement

I want my 'if' statement to execute at particular values of a counter variable 'i' where 'i' ranges from 1:100 and 'if' statement should execute at i=10,20,30,40,..100. How can I set the condition with 'if' statement?

```
for i=1:100
if i=10||20||30||40||50||60||70||80||90||100
fprintf('this is multiple of 10') % 1st section
else
fprintf('this is not multiple of 10') % 2nd section
end
```

I expect that '1st section should only execute when 'i' equals multiple of 10 but in actual, '1st section' executes always.

Comment: The correct logic is “i is 10 or i is 20 or i is 30 or...”

Comment: You can also use `if mod(i,10)  == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case (i.e. is a number a multiple of 10), the [answer from machnic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764730/52738) using the [`mod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) (or [`rem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rem.html)) function is the best approach:

```
if mod(i, 10) == 0 ...
% Or
if rem(i, 10) == 0 ...
```

For a more general case (i.e. is a number in a given set), you have a few options. You could use the [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function on the result of a [vectorized equality](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) comparison:

```
if any(i == 10:10:100) ...
```

Or you could use the [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
if ismember(i, 10:10:100) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, for such simple condition you can use `mod` function:

```
for i = 1:100
    if mod(i, 10) == 0
        fprintf('%i - this is multiple of 10\n', i) % 1st section
    else
        fprintf('%i - this is not multiple of 10\n', i) % 2nd section
    end
end
```